# Number of distinct conjugates of a subgroup is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.  I would like to prove that if $H$ has finite index in $G$, then there is only a finite number of distinct subgroups in $G$ of the form $aHa^{-1}$.  (This is an exercise in [Herstein, Topics in Algebra], in the section on subgroups and Lagrange's theorem.)

The assertion clearly holds if $|H|$ (or $|G|$) is finite.  Also, the number of distinct conjugates $aHa^{-1}$ is 1 if $H \trianglelefteq G$.  So we need to consider only the case $|H|=\infty, H \ntrianglelefteq G$. I am also wondering what would be some specific examples of such infinite groups $H \le G$ with $|G:H| < \infty$ and $H \ntrianglelefteq G$.

Comment: I am very poor at English. Herstein wrote "there **is** only a finite number of distinct subgroups in $G$ of the form $aHa^{-1}$.". But I think "there **are** only a finite number of distinct subgroups in $G$ of the form $aHa^{-1}$." is correct. Is "there **is**" an errata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you familiar with the concept of group actions? The group $G$ acts on the conjugacy class of $H$ via the conjugation action. There is only one orbit, and its stabilier is $N_G(H)$, hence the orbit is in (equivariant) bijection with the coset space $G/N_G(H)$ via $gN_G(H)\longleftrightarrow gHg^{-1}$.

But $H\le N_G(H)\le G$ so $N_G(H)$ has finite index, so $G/N_G(H)$ is finite.

The class of profinite groups exhibits a large number of examples of groups with subgroups of finite index - in fact they have topology which is defined in terms of them.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I don't see why the stabilizer is $N_G(H)$. Define $\phi: g N_G(H) \mapsto gHg^{-1}$. We have that $aN_G(H)=bN_G(H)$ iff $a^{-1}b \in N_G(H)$ iff $a^{-1}b H (a^{-1}b)^{-1} =H$ iff $bHb^{-1}=aHa^{-1}$, whence $\phi$ is well-defined and bijective, so that answers the question by your argument.  Let $C:=\{aHa^{-1}: a \in G\}$, and let $G$ act on $C$ by conjugation, so $g: aHa^{-1} \mapsto g(aHa^{-1})g^{-1}$.  The stabilizer (i.e. kernel) is $\{x \in G: x(aHa^{-1})x^{-1}=aHa^{-1}, \forall a \in G\}$. I don't see why this set is $N_G(H)$.

Comment: @AG. Sorry for the confusion, I mean the stabilizer of a specific point in the conjugacy class, in particular $H$. In general, if $G$ acts on $X$, then the orbit of $x\in X$ is in bijection with the coset space $G/S$, where $S$ is the stabilizer of $x$. The stabilizers of distinct points in an orbit will often be distinct subgroups of $G$, but said stabilizers will always be *conjugate* which means the coset spaces will be isomorphic, which is why we can choose without loss of generality the stabilizer $N_G(H)$ of $H$ for our purposes.

Comment: You are correct that the full stabilizer - the subgroup of $G$ fixing pointwise (under conjugation) each and every conjugate of $H$ individually is in fact the so-called "normal core" of $H$ (the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ that is contained in $H$).

Answer (score 2):

I want to give an explicit answer to the last part of your question, as otherwise this is pretty much a duplicate...

So, what is a group which has a non-normal finite-index subgroup? Take an arbitrary infinite group $H$, for example the infinite cyclic group $H=C_{\infty}\cong \mathbb{Z}$, and take its cross-product with a non-abelian finite simple group $S$, for example $S=A_5$. Form the group $G=H\times S$.

As $S$ is non-abelian it has a proper, non-trivial subgroup $K$. Then the subgroup $H\times K\leq G$ is not normal in $G$, but does have finite index.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
This problem is Problem 19 on p.48.
I solved this problem as follows:

> $$aHa^{-1}=bHb^{-1}\Leftrightarrow (b^{-1}a)H(b^{-1}a)^{-1}=H\\\Leftrightarrow b^{-1}a\in N(H):=\{a\in G\mid aHa^{-1}=H\}.$$
> See Problem 16 on p.47 about the subgroup $N(H)$ of $G$.
> Obviously, $N(H)\supset H$.
> By assumption, $i_G(H)=\#G/H<+\infty$.
> So, $i_G(N(H))<+\infty$.
> Note that $i_G(N(H))$ is equal to the number of distinct subgroups in $G$ of the form $aHa^{-1}$.